# Firebase duplicates its nodes when users updates his profile (in my case dp and status)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am having app where users can post ideas and update their profile picture and status message which is connected to firebase

[firebase database screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCkFz.png)

> for instance, if I update status message as mentioned in above image marked in blue, The data which is marked in red duplicates as with new key

firebase database locations

users details are saved in **firebase root** > **users**

user post(ideas) are saved in **firebase root** > **ideas** and **user-ideas**

I'm facing a bug when...

> Open app
>
> post new Idea
>
> after posting new idea (without closing app) if I go to profile settings and update the status or profile picture the above idea (or very recent one idea is duplicating itself.

here is the code

1) new idea activity class to post by users

```
'https://pastebin.com/Pzq9mjkD'
```

2) user profile activity class to change profile picture

```
'https://pastebin.com/ZmmCkKzP'
```

Comment: Why are you generating a new key? You should look at the `update` method. You pass the full path of the object you want to change, and update it, instead of pushing a new record to the DB.

Comment: thanks for the comment but I did not understand where should update

Answer (score 0):

`push` is used to add a new element to the database.
`update` is used to update an existing element.

```
    String key = mDatabase.child("ideas").push().getKey();
    Idea idea = new Idea(date, userId, username, script_name, action, entryPrice, period, target,
            stop_loss, script_views, thumbImgSrc);
    Map<String, Object> ideaValues = idea.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/ideas/" + key, ideaValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-ideas/" + userId + "/" + key, ideaValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Your code is always generating a new key `mDatabase.child("ideas").push().getKey();` then saving that new record.

Instead of generating a new key each time you should update your existing records, why not try dropping the key and just writing to the `ideas` and `user-ideas` with the `userId` key?

```
childUpdates.put("/ideas/" + userId, ideaValues);
childUpdates.put("/user-ideas/" + userId, ideaValues);
```

Comment: Yeah your answer is right But my problem is when I update/change profile (like status or profile picture) the very recent idea is duplicating every time when I update status/profile picture here is firebase database screenshot [link](
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B87m8ZeJas4GM0hBLTZsOFB5Umc/view?usp=sharing) when I change (marked in red) ideas are duplicating (marked in blue)